# Jboss managed server stops between deployments

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian to run integration tests. The tool is great, however I am not sure if I am using it correctly. The matter is that after each deployment (I have one deployment per test suite) jboss stops and starts again. It is very annoying as because of it time of running suites is very big. Is there any way to make jboss not restart between deployments?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess it's because you are running your Arquillian tests on an embedded container (like [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly/wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded) one) which by design automatically stops when the test suite finishes.

You can deploy your tests on a running application server and it wouldn't automatically shut down.

Comment: Yes I am using embedded container. So there is no way to make it not to stop after each suite?

Comment: I don't think you can manually manage this type of container.